# Create "static" HTML Pages For Each Product

Tags: html, django, static

I have 10k+ products that need their HTML Page and the stuff within is to be static (thus searchable). I am trying to find a way to do the following using `django`:

- Loop over all the items.
- Get the matching information.
- Fill a model template.
- Save such template with the information now static.

As much as I tried looking here on Stack Overflow and in the web, I did not find any instructions to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Build a standard template that has variables for the products. Then on the backend you can search for the products you want and populate the template with their information. Something like this for a concept:

**search.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'your_url' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <input type=text name=input value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

**product.html**

```
<html>
    <div>Hello {{name}}!</div>
</html>
```

**models.py**

```
class Names:
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

**views.py**

```
input = request.POST['input']
name = Names.objects.get(user_name=input)
return render_to_response('product.html', {'name': name})
```

This will allow your user to search something, pull up the record searched, and place it in the template.

You can use that system for any number of variables.